# Center a relative element with Jquery animate

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div  #sample with relative position and no predefined width; I want to center it after having moved it away, with the following commands:

```
$('#sample').animate({
    "left": -3000
}, 1500);
$('#sample').animate({
    'left': x
}, 1500);
```

My problem is I do not know how to calculate x. In case #sample would be absolute positioned I knew it. However, I want relative position and $("#sample").width() does not coincide with its real width as to use it for finding the center. Any idea for helping me?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the width of the element and its parent element then you can center it as follows,

```
var elemWidth = $('#sample').width();
var parentWidth = $('#sample').parent().width();
$('#sample').animate({ 'left': (parentWidth/2-elemWidth/2)}, 1500 );
```

**example**

http://jsfiddle.net/wQ3K7/

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sample').animate({ "left": -3000 }, 1500 );
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
        var elemWidth = $('#sample').width();
        var parentWidth = $('#sample').parent().width();
        $('#sample').animate({ 'left': (parentWidth/2-elemWidth/2)}, 1500 );
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<div id="sample">this is a test</div>
<input type="button" value="animate"/>
```

**css**

```
div{
    position:relative;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    width:200px;/*random width*/
}
```